# Why won't my AJAX form validate?

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, validation

I'm having some trouble with the jquery validate plugin, I am writing a project for car dealers to book radio repairs and need to send information to my server via an AJAX form, which at the moment isn't validating at all for some reason.

This is puzzling, as I'm using precisely the same kind of code on another form, which works fine!

could anyone point me in the right direction with this please?

code is below

**View**

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")

@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")

<!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")

@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryunobtrusive")
<!-- Metis Menu Plugin JavaScript -->
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Content/lib/metisMenu/dist/metisMenu.min.js")"></script>

<!-- Custom Theme JavaScript -->
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Content/js/sb-admin-2.js")"></script>

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Content/lib/bootstap-wizard/jquery.bootstrap.wizard.min.js")"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js")"></script>
<script src=@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js")></script>
<script src=@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")></script>



<!-- Custom CSS -->
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/css/main.css")" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Custom Fonts -->
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/lib/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">





<!-- Custom Fonts -->



<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/awesome-bootstrap-checkbox.css")" rel="stylesheet" />

@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("BookRepair", "Dealer", null, new AjaxOptions
{
    HttpMethod = "POST",
    OnSuccess = "Success",
    OnFailure = "Failure",
    UpdateTargetId = "SuccessText",
    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace

}, new { @class = "form-horizontal" }))
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class="text-danger"})
    <div class="container-fluid" id="PageContainer">
        <div id="rootwizard">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab">Exchange Details</a></li>
                <li><a href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab">Vehicle Details</a></li>
                <li><a href="#tab3" data-toggle="tab">Defect Details</a></li>
                <li><a href="#tab4" data-toggle="tab" id="AddInfo">Trapped Items</a></li>
                <li><a href="#tab5" data-toggle="tab">Terms and Conditions</a></li>


            </ul>
            <br />
            <div class="col-md-6">


                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="container-fluid">
                        <div class="panel-body">


                            <div class="tab-content">
                                <div class="tab-pane" id="tab1">
                                    <h1>Radio or Cluster?</h1>

                                    <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
                                        <label class="btn btn-default" id="IsRadio">
                                            @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.IsRadioRepair, new { @type = "radio", @value="True", @class = "btn btn-primary" }) Radio
                                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.IsRadioRepair, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                        </label>
                                        <label class="btn btn-default" id="IsCluster">
                                            <input type="radio" value="False" class="btn btn-primary"> Cluster
                                        </label>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="Requesttype">
                                        <h4>Type of Request</h4>
                                        <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
                                            <label class="btn btn-default" id="IsAdvanceRepair">
                                                @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.IsDirectRepair, new { @type = "radio", @value = "false", @class = "btn btn-primary" }) Advance Repair
                                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.IsDirectRepair, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                            </label>
                                            <label class="btn btn-default" id="RepairBtn">
                                                <input type="radio" value="True" class="btn btn-primary"> Direct Repair
                                            </label>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>


                                    <div id="warranty-container-Adv">
                                        <h4>Unit is in Warranty?</h4>
                                        @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.WarrantyTypeOptions, "PDI Warranty", new { @value = "PDI" }) PDI Warranty
                                        @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.WarrantyTypeOptions, "non PDI Warranty", new { @value = "NoPDI" }) non PDI Warranty
                                        @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.WarrantyTypeOptions, "Not in Warranty", new { @value = "NoWarranty" }) Not In Warranty
                                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.WarrantyTypeOptions, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                    </div>

                                    <div id="warranty-container-Dir">
                                        <h4>Unit is in Warranty?</h4>

                                        @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.WarrantyTypeOptions, "In Warranty", new { @value = "ClusterHasWarranty" }) In Warranty
                                        @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.WarrantyTypeOptions, "Not in Warranty", new { @value = "ClusterNoWarranty" }) Not In Warranty
                                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.WarrantyTypeOptions, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-12">
                                        <ul class="pager wizard">




                                            <li class="next"><a href="#tab2">Next</a></li>


                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="tab-pane" id="tab2">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <h4>Vehicle Sale Date</h4>
                                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.VehicleSaleDate, new { @class = "form-control datepicker", @placeholder = "Please select..." })
                                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.VehicleSaleDate, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

                                        <h4>Claim Number</h4>
                                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ClaimNumber, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "E.G 12ER34" })
                                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.ClaimNumber, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                        <h4>VIN Number</h4>
                                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.VIN, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Please enter VIN number" })
                                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.VIN, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

                                        <h4>Vehicle Registration Number</h4>
                                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.VehicleRegNo, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Please enter Car Registration number" })

                                        <h4>Miles/KM</h4>
                                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Mileage, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Please enter Mileage in KM or Miles" })
                                        <ul class="pager wizard">

                                            <li class="previous"><a href="#tab1">Previous</a></li>
                                            <li class="next"><a href="#tab3">Next</a></li>

                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="tab-pane" id="tab3">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <h4>Part Number</h4>
                                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.PartNumber, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Please enter Part Number" })
                                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.PartNumber, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                        <button class="btn btn-success" title="" data-placement="bottom" data-toggle="tooltip" type="button" data-original-title="You can find the part number on the label" style="float: right">Where?</button>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <h4>Bezel Colour</h4>
                                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.BezelColor, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Please enter Bezel Color" })
                                        <br />
                                        <h4>Type</h4>
                                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Type, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Type" })
                                        <br />
                                        <h4>Serial Number</h4>
                                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Serial, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Serial Number" })
                                        <br />
                                        <h4>Labour hours</h4>
                                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.LabourHours, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Labour hours" })
                                        <br />
                                        <h4>Defect Description</h4>
                                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.DefectDesc, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "E.G Poor display, Customer Damage, Navigation issues, etc" })
                                        <br />
                                        <h4>Status of the Defect</h4>
                                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Condition, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Inoperative, happens over time, intermittent etc" })
                                        <br />
                                        <h4>Reported issue(s)</h4>
                                        @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.CustomerComplaint, new { @class = "form-control", @style = "max-width:100%; max-height:100%;resize:none", @placeholder = "Please enter customer's complaint as Reported" })



                                    </div>
                                    <ul class="pager wizard">
                                        <li class="previous"><a href="#tab1">Previous</a></li>
                                        <li class="next"><a href="#tab3">Next</a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                       </div>
                                <div class="tab-pane" id="tab4">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <h4 id="TrappedItemContainer0">Does the Unit have any trapped Items?</h4>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons"id="TrappedItemContainer1">
                                        <label class="btn btn-default" id="HasTrappedItems">
                                            @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.HasTrappedItems, new { @type = "radio", @class = "btn btn-primary" }) Yes
                                        </label>
                                        <label class="btn btn-default" id="NoTrappedItems">
                                            <input type="radio" value="IsAdvance" class="btn btn-primary"> No
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                           <div id="TrappedItemContainer">    

                                            <h4>Trapped Item 1</h4>
                                            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.TrappedItem1, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "CD/DVD Title, artist etc" })

                                            <br />
                                            <h4>Trapped Item 2</h4>
                                            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.TrappedItem2, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "CD/DVD Title, artist etc" })
                                            <br />
                                            <h4>Trapped Item 3</h4>
                                            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.TrappedItem3, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "CD/DVD Title, artist etc" })
                                            <br />
                                            <h4>Trapped Item 4</h4>
                                            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.TrappedItem4, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "CD/DVD Title, artist etc" })
                                            <br />
                                            <h4>Trapped Item 5</h4>
                                            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.TrappedItem5, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "CD/DVD Title, artist etc" })
                                            <br />
                                            <h4>Trapped Item 6</h4>
                                            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.TrappedItem6, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "CD/DVD Title, artist etc" })
                                            <br />


                                    </div>

                                    <h4>Additional Comments</h4>
                                    @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.AdditionalComments, new { @class = "form-control", @style = "max-width:100%; max-height:100%;resize:none", @placeholder = "Any other Additional Information" })
                                    <ul class="pager wizard">

                                        <li class="previous"><a href="#tab3">Previous</a></li>
                                        <li class="next"><a href="#tab5">Next</a></li>


                                    </ul>
                                </div>



                                <div class="tab-pane" id="tab5">
                                    <div class="col-md-12">



                                        <h3>Terms + Conditions</h3>
                                        Tincidunt integer eu augue augue nunc elit dolor, luctus placerat scelerisque euismod, iaculis eu lacus nunc mi elit, vehicula ut laoreet ac, aliquam sit amet justo nunc tempor, metus vel.
                                        Placerat suscipit, orci nisl iaculis eros, a tincidunt nisi odio eget lorem nulla condimentum tempor mattis ut vitae feugiat augue cras ut metus a risus iaculis scelerisque eu ac ante.
                                        Fusce non varius purus aenean nec magna felis fusce vestibulum velit mollis odio sollicitudin lacinia aliquam posuere, sapien elementum lob ortis tincidunt, turpis dui ornare nisl, sollicitudin interdum turpis nunc eget.

                                        <br />

                                        <ol type="I">
                                            <br />
                                            <li>
                                                Tincidunt integer eu augue augue nunc elit dolor, luctus placerat scelerisque euismod, iaculis eu lacus nunc mi elit, vehicula ut laoreet ac, aliquam sit amet justo nunc tempor, metus vel.
                                                Placerat suscipit, orci nisl iaculis eros, a tincidunt nisi odio eget lorem nulla condimentum tempor mattis ut vitae feugiat augue cras ut metus a risus iaculis scelerisque eu ac ante.
                                                Fusce non varius purus aenean nec magna felis fusce vestibulum velit mollis odio sollicitudin lacinia aliquam posuere, sapien elementum lobortis tincidunt, turpis dui ornare nisl, sollicitudin interdum turpis nunc eget.
                                                Sem nulla eu ultricies orci praesent id augue nec lorem pretium congue sit amet ac nunc fusce iaculis lorem eu diam hendrerit at mattis purus dignissim vivamus mauris tellus, fringilla.
                                            </li>
                                            <br />

                                            <li>
                                                Tincidunt integer eu augue augue nunc elit dolor, luctus placerat scelerisque euismod, iaculis eu lacus nunc mi elit, vehicula ut laoreet ac, aliquam sit amet justo nunc tempor, metus vel.
                                                Placerat suscipit, orci nisl iaculis eros, a tincidunt nisi odio eget lorem nulla condimentum tempor mattis ut vitae feugiat augue cras ut metus a risus iaculis scelerisque eu ac ante.
                                                Fusce non varius purus aenean nec magna felis fusce vestibulum velit mollis odio sollicitudin lacinia aliquam posuere, sapien elementum lobortis tincidunt, turpis dui ornare nisl, sollicitudin interdum turpis nunc eget.
                                            </li>
                                            <br />

                                            <li>
                                                Tincidunt integer eu augue augue nunc elit dolor, luctus placerat scelerisque euismod, iaculis eu lacus nunc mi elit, vehicula ut laoreet ac, aliquam sit amet justo nunc tempor, metus vel.
                                                Placerat suscipit
                                            </li>
                                            <br />
                                            <li>
                                                Tincidunt integer eu augue augue nunc elit dolor, luctus placerat scelerisque euismod, iaculis eu lacus nunc mi elit, vehicula ut laoreet ac, aliquam sit amet justo nunc tempor, metus vel.
                                                Placerat suscipit
                                            </li>
                                            <br />
                                            <li>
                                                Placerat suscipit, orci nisl iaculis eros, a tincidunt nisi odio eget lorem nulla condimentum tempor mattis ut vitae feugiat augue cras ut metus a risus iaculis scelerisque eu ac ante.
                                                Fusce non varius purus aenean nec magna felis fusce vestibulum velit mollis odio sollicitudin lacinia aliquam posuere, sapien elementum lob ortis tincidunt, turpis dui ornare nisl, sollicitudin interdum turpis nunc eget.
                                            </li>
                                            <br />

                                        </ol>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-12" style="text-align:center;">

                                        <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
                                            <label class="btn btn-default" id="TCAgree">
                                                <input type="radio" value="IsAccepted" class="btn btn-primary"> I agree
                                            </label>
                                            <label class="btn btn-default" id="TCNotAgree">
                                                <input type="radio" value="IsRefused" class="btn btn-primary"> I do not Agree
                                            </label>
                                        </div>
                                        <br />
                                        <br />

                                        <div id="AjaxLoader">
                                            <button type="submit" class=" btn btn-success" style="text-align:right;" @*value="submit"*@ id="SubmitBtn"> Submit Request</button>
                                            <ul class="pager wizard">
                                                <li class="previous"><a href="#tab4">Previous</a></li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <br/>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

}
```

these are the scripts I'm loading in through my _Layout page

```
  @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")

    <!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryunobtrusive")
    <!-- Metis Menu Plugin JavaScript -->
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Content/lib/metisMenu/dist/metisMenu.min.js")"></script>

    <!-- Custom Theme JavaScript -->
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Content/js/sb-admin-2.js")"></script>

    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Content/lib/bootstap-wizard/jquery.bootstrap.wizard.min.js")"></script>



    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")

    <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css")" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- MetisMenu CSS -->
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/lib/metisMenu/dist/metisMenu.min.css")" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/css/main.css")" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom Fonts -->
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/lib/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
```

my Controller at this point just calls a web service which inserts the data, the main issue is just the front/back end validation.

Comment: You have multiple duplicate scripts all over the place. Ensure you have only one of each and they are loaded in the correct order

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your view should be

```
<!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css")" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- MetisMenu CSS -->
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/lib/metisMenu/dist/metisMenu.min.css")" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/awesome-bootstrap-checkbox.css")" rel="stylesheet" />


@using (Ajax.BeginForm("BookRepair", "Dealer", null, new AjaxOptions
{
    HttpMethod = "POST",
    OnSuccess = "Success",
    OnFailure = "Failure",
    UpdateTargetId = "SuccessText",
    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace

}, new { @class = "form-horizontal" }))
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class="text-danger"})
    <div class="container-fluid" id="PageContainer">
        <div id="rootwizard">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab">Exchange Details</a></li>
                <li><a href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab">Vehicle Details</a></li>
                <li><a href="#tab3" data-toggle="tab">Defect Details</a></li>
                <li><a href="#tab4" data-toggle="tab" id="AddInfo">Trapped Items</a></li>
                <li><a href="#tab5" data-toggle="tab">Terms and Conditions</a></li>


            </ul>
            <br />
            <div class="col-md-6">


                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="container-fluid">
                        <div class="panel-body">


                            <div class="tab-content">
                                <div class="tab-pane" id="tab1">
                                    <h1>Radio or Cluster?</h1>

                                    <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
                                        <label class="btn btn-default" id="IsRadio">
                                            @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.IsRadioRepair, new { @type = "radio", @value="True", @class = "btn btn-primary" }) Radio
                                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.IsRadioRepair, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                        </label>
                                        <label class="btn btn-default" id="IsCluster">
                                            <input type="radio" value="False" class="btn btn-primary"> Cluster
                                        </label>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="Requesttype">
                                        <h4>Type of Request</h4>
                                        <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
                                            <label class="btn btn-default" id="IsAdvanceRepair">
                                                @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.IsDirectRepair, new { @type = "radio", @value = "false", @class = "btn btn-primary" }) Advance Repair
                                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.IsDirectRepair, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                            </label>
                                            <label class="btn btn-default" id="RepairBtn">
                                                <input type="radio" value="True" class="btn btn-primary"> Direct Repair
                                            </label>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>


                                    <div id="warranty-container-Adv">
                                        <h4>Unit is in Warranty?</h4>
                                        @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.WarrantyTypeOptions, "PDI Warranty", new { @value = "PDI" }) PDI Warranty
                                        @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.WarrantyTypeOptions, "non PDI Warranty", new { @value = "NoPDI" }) non PDI Warranty
                                        @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.WarrantyTypeOptions, "Not in Warranty", new { @value = "NoWarranty" }) Not In Warranty
                                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.WarrantyTypeOptions, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                    </div>

                                    <div id="warranty-container-Dir">
                                        <h4>Unit is in Warranty?</h4>

                                        @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.WarrantyTypeOptions, "In Warranty", new { @value = "ClusterHasWarranty" }) In Warranty
                                        @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.WarrantyTypeOptions, "Not in Warranty", new { @value = "ClusterNoWarranty" }) Not In Warranty
                                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.WarrantyTypeOptions, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-12">
                                        <ul class="pager wizard">




                                            <li class="next"><a href="#tab2">Next</a></li>


                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="tab-pane" id="tab2">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <h4>Vehicle Sale Date</h4>
                                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.VehicleSaleDate, new { @class = "form-control datepicker", @placeholder = "Please select..." })
                                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.VehicleSaleDate, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

                                        <h4>Claim Number</h4>
                                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ClaimNumber, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "E.G 12ER34" })
                                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.ClaimNumber, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                        <h4>VIN Number</h4>
                                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.VIN, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Please enter VIN number" })
                                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.VIN, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

                                        <h4>Vehicle Registration Number</h4>
                                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.VehicleRegNo, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Please enter Car Registration number" })

                                        <h4>Miles/KM</h4>
                                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Mileage, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Please enter Mileage in KM or Miles" })
                                        <ul class="pager wizard">

                                            <li class="previous"><a href="#tab1">Previous</a></li>
                                            <li class="next"><a href="#tab3">Next</a></li>

                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="tab-pane" id="tab3">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <h4>Part Number</h4>
                                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.PartNumber, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Please enter Part Number" })
                                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.PartNumber, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                        <button class="btn btn-success" title="" data-placement="bottom" data-toggle="tooltip" type="button" data-original-title="You can find the part number on the label" style="float: right">Where?</button>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <h4>Bezel Colour</h4>
                                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.BezelColor, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Please enter Bezel Color" })
                                        <br />
                                        <h4>Type</h4>
                                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Type, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Type" })
                                        <br />
                                        <h4>Serial Number</h4>
                                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Serial, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Serial Number" })
                                        <br />
                                        <h4>Labour hours</h4>
                                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.LabourHours, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Labour hours" })
                                        <br />
                                        <h4>Defect Description</h4>
                                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.DefectDesc, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "E.G Poor display, Customer Damage, Navigation issues, etc" })
                                        <br />
                                        <h4>Status of the Defect</h4>
                                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Condition, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Inoperative, happens over time, intermittent etc" })
                                        <br />
                                        <h4>Reported issue(s)</h4>
                                        @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.CustomerComplaint, new { @class = "form-control", @style = "max-width:100%; max-height:100%;resize:none", @placeholder = "Please enter customer's complaint as Reported" })



                                    </div>
                                    <ul class="pager wizard">
                                        <li class="previous"><a href="#tab1">Previous</a></li>
                                        <li class="next"><a href="#tab3">Next</a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                       </div>
                                <div class="tab-pane" id="tab4">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <h4 id="TrappedItemContainer0">Does the Unit have any trapped Items?</h4>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons"id="TrappedItemContainer1">
                                        <label class="btn btn-default" id="HasTrappedItems">
                                            @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.HasTrappedItems, new { @type = "radio", @class = "btn btn-primary" }) Yes
                                        </label>
                                        <label class="btn btn-default" id="NoTrappedItems">
                                            <input type="radio" value="IsAdvance" class="btn btn-primary"> No
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                           <div id="TrappedItemContainer">    

                                            <h4>Trapped Item 1</h4>
                                            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.TrappedItem1, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "CD/DVD Title, artist etc" })

                                            <br />
                                            <h4>Trapped Item 2</h4>
                                            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.TrappedItem2, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "CD/DVD Title, artist etc" })
                                            <br />
                                            <h4>Trapped Item 3</h4>
                                            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.TrappedItem3, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "CD/DVD Title, artist etc" })
                                            <br />
                                            <h4>Trapped Item 4</h4>
                                            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.TrappedItem4, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "CD/DVD Title, artist etc" })
                                            <br />
                                            <h4>Trapped Item 5</h4>
                                            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.TrappedItem5, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "CD/DVD Title, artist etc" })
                                            <br />
                                            <h4>Trapped Item 6</h4>
                                            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.TrappedItem6, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "CD/DVD Title, artist etc" })
                                            <br />


                                    </div>

                                    <h4>Additional Comments</h4>
                                    @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.AdditionalComments, new { @class = "form-control", @style = "max-width:100%; max-height:100%;resize:none", @placeholder = "Any other Additional Information" })
                                    <ul class="pager wizard">

                                        <li class="previous"><a href="#tab3">Previous</a></li>
                                        <li class="next"><a href="#tab5">Next</a></li>


                                    </ul>
                                </div>



                                <div class="tab-pane" id="tab5">
                                    <div class="col-md-12">



                                        <h3>Terms + Conditions</h3>
                                        Tincidunt integer eu augue augue nunc elit dolor, luctus placerat scelerisque euismod, iaculis eu lacus nunc mi elit, vehicula ut laoreet ac, aliquam sit amet justo nunc tempor, metus vel.
                                        Placerat suscipit, orci nisl iaculis eros, a tincidunt nisi odio eget lorem nulla condimentum tempor mattis ut vitae feugiat augue cras ut metus a risus iaculis scelerisque eu ac ante.
                                        Fusce non varius purus aenean nec magna felis fusce vestibulum velit mollis odio sollicitudin lacinia aliquam posuere, sapien elementum lob ortis tincidunt, turpis dui ornare nisl, sollicitudin interdum turpis nunc eget.

                                        <br />

                                        <ol type="I">
                                            <br />
                                            <li>
                                                Tincidunt integer eu augue augue nunc elit dolor, luctus placerat scelerisque euismod, iaculis eu lacus nunc mi elit, vehicula ut laoreet ac, aliquam sit amet justo nunc tempor, metus vel.
                                                Placerat suscipit, orci nisl iaculis eros, a tincidunt nisi odio eget lorem nulla condimentum tempor mattis ut vitae feugiat augue cras ut metus a risus iaculis scelerisque eu ac ante.
                                                Fusce non varius purus aenean nec magna felis fusce vestibulum velit mollis odio sollicitudin lacinia aliquam posuere, sapien elementum lobortis tincidunt, turpis dui ornare nisl, sollicitudin interdum turpis nunc eget.
                                                Sem nulla eu ultricies orci praesent id augue nec lorem pretium congue sit amet ac nunc fusce iaculis lorem eu diam hendrerit at mattis purus dignissim vivamus mauris tellus, fringilla.
                                            </li>
                                            <br />

                                            <li>
                                                Tincidunt integer eu augue augue nunc elit dolor, luctus placerat scelerisque euismod, iaculis eu lacus nunc mi elit, vehicula ut laoreet ac, aliquam sit amet justo nunc tempor, metus vel.
                                                Placerat suscipit, orci nisl iaculis eros, a tincidunt nisi odio eget lorem nulla condimentum tempor mattis ut vitae feugiat augue cras ut metus a risus iaculis scelerisque eu ac ante.
                                                Fusce non varius purus aenean nec magna felis fusce vestibulum velit mollis odio sollicitudin lacinia aliquam posuere, sapien elementum lobortis tincidunt, turpis dui ornare nisl, sollicitudin interdum turpis nunc eget.
                                            </li>
                                            <br />

                                            <li>
                                                Tincidunt integer eu augue augue nunc elit dolor, luctus placerat scelerisque euismod, iaculis eu lacus nunc mi elit, vehicula ut laoreet ac, aliquam sit amet justo nunc tempor, metus vel.
                                                Placerat suscipit
                                            </li>
                                            <br />
                                            <li>
                                                Tincidunt integer eu augue augue nunc elit dolor, luctus placerat scelerisque euismod, iaculis eu lacus nunc mi elit, vehicula ut laoreet ac, aliquam sit amet justo nunc tempor, metus vel.
                                                Placerat suscipit
                                            </li>
                                            <br />
                                            <li>
                                                Placerat suscipit, orci nisl iaculis eros, a tincidunt nisi odio eget lorem nulla condimentum tempor mattis ut vitae feugiat augue cras ut metus a risus iaculis scelerisque eu ac ante.
                                                Fusce non varius purus aenean nec magna felis fusce vestibulum velit mollis odio sollicitudin lacinia aliquam posuere, sapien elementum lob ortis tincidunt, turpis dui ornare nisl, sollicitudin interdum turpis nunc eget.
                                            </li>
                                            <br />

                                        </ol>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-12" style="text-align:center;">

                                        <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
                                            <label class="btn btn-default" id="TCAgree">
                                                <input type="radio" value="IsAccepted" class="btn btn-primary"> I agree
                                            </label>
                                            <label class="btn btn-default" id="TCNotAgree">
                                                <input type="radio" value="IsRefused" class="btn btn-primary"> I do not Agree
                                            </label>
                                        </div>
                                        <br />
                                        <br />

                                        <div id="AjaxLoader">
                                            <button type="submit" class=" btn btn-success" style="text-align:right;" @*value="submit"*@ id="SubmitBtn"> Submit Request</button>
                                            <ul class="pager wizard">
                                                <li class="previous"><a href="#tab4">Previous</a></li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <br/>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, the form validation is working but how come it's still letting me POST values to my controller when I don't put information into required fields?